# Solving Project Euler #4 with C language

Tags: c, project

I tried to solve Problem 4 of Project Euler with C language but get wrong answers all the time.

```
// Project Euler - Problem 5 
// 09/01/2014
#include <stdio.h>

int a,b,c,digits[14],e,y,z,biggestNum;

void isPalindrome (int x)
{
    a = -1;
    c = 0;
    b = x;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        digits[c] = (b % 10);
        b=b/10;
        c++;
    }
    while (c>=a)
    {
        if(digits[++a]!=digits[--c])
        {
            break;
        }
        if(a==c) {  biggestNum=x; }
        else if(a==c-1) {   biggestNum=x; }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    for(y=10; y<1000; y++)
    {
        for(z=10; z<1000; z++)
        {
            isPalindrome(y*z);
        }
    }
    printf ("%d",biggestNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code? Maybe in checking if the num is Palindrome function?
thanks 
[The Problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4)

Comment: It will be much helpful if you provide the link to the problem in your post itself.

Comment: Well, provided your isPalindrome function is 90% of the source code, and the remaining 10% is the mainline, there's a very good chance the problem is in the isPalindrome function. You may want to look there and do some debugging. Does it correctly detect palindromes? Does it correctly reject numbers that are not palindromes?

Comment: What does your code print?

Comment: It is print the largest palindrome number made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Comment: Yes there's a problem with `isPalindrome` function. A function named `is<something>` should return a single Boolean value and do nothing more. It's a law set in stone. Your function returns `void`. Thus the function is not acceptable no matter what it does.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: the actual output is 90909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't find the biggest Palindrome, it finds the last Palindrome if you run through the numbers

```
10* 10, 10 * 11, 10 * 12, .... 10 * 999
...
999 * 10, 999 * 11, ....       999 * 999
```

If the largest palindrome happens to be (say) 750 * 750, but also 999 * 11 is a Palindrome, the 999 * 11 will overwrite the correct answer.

You need to test each time that your answer is bigger than the previous biggest answer you had.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem after i fixed the code it output the number 906609 that is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can improve the foor loop with the following:

```
    for(y = 999; y >= 100 ; --y)
    {
        for(z = y; z >= 100; --z)
        {
            if (isPalindrome(y*z)) {
                return y*z; // TODO: use temp var
            }
        }
    }
```

1. It will be easier to convert the number to string and the check using n/2 steps (being n the number of digits)

```
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != str(n-i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
```

Comment: Why not start from 999 down to 100, after all we want largest palindrome, the first palindrome you will get this way will be the answer.

Comment: You are right, and my answer is wrong in the sense that `999 * 999` is not calculated, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    while (c>=a)
    {
        if(digits[++a]!=digits[--c])
        {
            break;
        }
        if(a==c) {  biggestNum=x; }
        else if(a==c-1) {   biggestNum=x; }
    }
```

to

```
    while (c > a){
        if(digits[++a]!=digits[--c])
            return ;
    }
    if(x>biggestNum)//bigger than old value
        biggestNum=x;
```