# Incorrect solution to Project Euler Problem 4

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm fairly new to programming. I've created a solution to problem 4 on Project Euler. However, my code seems to have a problem and doesn't give me the desired result. The problem at hand is to find the largest palindrome created by multiplying two 3 digit numbers. The code works fine when I start both the loops at 100 (which is to find the largest palindrome obtained by multiplying two 2 digit numbers). My output, in this case, is 90909, whereas it should be 906609. Can anyone please review my code and help me?

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int checkPalindrome(int);
int main()
{
    int prod;
    for(int i=1000;i>0;i--)
        for(int j=1000;j>0;j--)
        {
            prod=i*j;
            if(checkPalindrome(prod))
        {      cout<<prod;
               cout<<endl;
               exit(0);
        }
        }
}

int checkPalindrome(int x)
{
    int temp=0,copy;
    copy=x;
    while(x!=0){
        temp=temp*10+(x%10);
        x/=10;
    }
    if(copy==temp)
        return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving Project Euler #4 with C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024509/solving-project-euler-4-with-c-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not actually searching for the largest palindrome created by multiplying two 3 digit numbers with your solution but you are instead searching for the first palindrome that the loops find. You can make it right like this:

```
int main()
{
    int prod;
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
         for (int j = 1000; j > 0; j--)
        {
            prod = i*j;
            if (checkPalindrome(prod) && res < prod)
            {
                res = prod;
            }
        }
    cout << res;
    cout << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```